# react-keyed-file-browser , 1.8.0 to 1.9.0 "this._fileBrowser.child" is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am sort of new in react and trying to update a project, the current version my project has is 1.8.0 and when i tried to update it to 1.9.0 , it started giving my error of undefined value
like i tried to

```
console.log (this._fileBrowser.child)
```

it gives value in 1.8.0 but in 1.9.0 it says undefined
I searched everywhere but was not able to find anything to resolve this issue ,
here is some part of my code.
getting error in this part

```
this.setState({
files: files, hasNext: response.data.has_next, lastPage: page, pageCount: response.data.count
}, () => {
window.removeEventListener('click', this._fileBrowser.child.handleGlobalClick);
window.addEventListener('click', this.handleGlobalClick);
});
```

this is the part where its getting its value

```
<FileBrowser
files={this.state.files}
canFilter={false}
ref={el => {
this._fileBrowser = el
}}
```

tried everything i could searched google, here, github docs n all